# marshal an unsigned char * returning function from a dll, in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, return, marshalling

I have the following function header in a native DLL:

```
unsigned char* Version_String()
```

I'm trying to call it from a C# project, I've tried the following call (as found on other similar questions here):

```
[DllImport("BSL430.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public extern static UIntPtr Version_String();
```

And I keep getting the following exception:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The next try was the following and I get the same exception:

```
[DllImport("BSL430.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
[return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public extern static string Version_String();
```

I can't seem to get around this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

I can't give the DLL code here, as it falls under an NDA, but the function I'm calling looks like this:

```
unsigned char versionString[50];

__declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* Version_String()
{
    if(check_hardware_stuff())
    {
      strcpy((char *) versionString, "version_string_bla_bla");
      versionString[5] = stuff;
    }
    else if (other_check())
    {
      //will return empty string, that should be filled with '\0'
    }
    else
    {
      strcpy( (char *) versionString, "ERROR" );
    }
  return versionString;
}
```

I'm not particularly fond of the DLL implementation, but I need to use it "as it is".
I get the exception thrown whenever I try to call `VersionString()`, regardless of what I do with the return value.

Comment: Maybe you're using wrong [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx)?

Comment: Does your dll was compiled with MultiByte charset option?

Comment: Use the debugger to find out where the native code crashes.  Project + Properties, Debug, tick "Enable unmanaged code debugging".  Set a breakpoint on the function in the C source code file.

Comment: @Hans Unfortunately I'm using the Express version, which does not support unmanaged code debugging. But thanks for the idea anyway, hopefully I'll be able to switch to the full version soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

Having seen the updated question, the various comments, and the code of your native function, it seems likely that the exception is raised when you call `check_hardware_stuff()`. It's simple enough to debug. I would replace your function with one like this:

unsigned char versionString[50];

```
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned char* Version_String()
{
    strcpy(versionString, "testing");
    return versionString;
}
```

If that still fails then my guess is that the error is raised in the `DllMain` of your DLL. Debug that by putting the above function into a plain vanilla DLL that does nothing else.

**Original answer**

Calling convention is the most obvious problem. Your native code most likely uses `cdecl` but the p/invoke default is `stdcall`. Change your p/invoke signature to be like this:

```
[DllImport("BSL430.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static IntPtr Version_String();
```

You can safely omit the `CharSet` parameter since none of the parameters have text because you are treating the return value as a pointer.

**Edit:** Hans correctly points out in the comments that since there are no parameters, the calling convention mis-match does not matter. So this isn't the problem.

Call [`Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx) to convert to a .net string.

```
string version = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Version_String());
```

Since `PtrToStringAnsi` is expecting an `IntPtr` parameter I would recommend that you use `IntPtr` as the return type of you p/invoke signature.

This all assumes that the memory returned from your native function is allocated and freed in the native DLL. If it is heap allocated and you expect the caller to deallocate it then you have a small problem. How do you deallocate the memory from C# since you don't have access to the native DLL's heap?

The simple solution is to use the shared COM heap to allocate the memory. Call `CoTaskMemAlloc` to allocate the buffer for the string. Then declare the return value to be of type `string` and the p/invoke marshaller will deallocate with the COM allocator.

```
[DllImport("BSL430.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static string Version_String();
...
string version = Version_String();
```

Of course, this only applies if you are returning heap allocated memory that you expect the caller to deallocate.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried the code, but I'm still getting the same exceptions. I got a look at the DLL code, and from what I can tell the string is globally declared as a fixed-size array: `unsigned char versionString[50];`. From what I know, no further allocations should be required in this case, right?

Comment: It can't be CallingConvention, the function doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: At what point do you get the exception? When calling the DLL, or when doing something with the value that is returned?

Comment: @David The exception triggers when calling Version_string(), regardless of whether I copy the return value to another variable or not.

Comment: @David I've edited the original post with some of the code in the DLL. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @David Thanks for your help. Indeed, it was an issue in the hardware, that caused the `hardware_check()` function to go crazy. I was so caught up with the types for marshalling, that I didn't think of looking at what's happening with the hardware.